# Retrieve product custom field values in checkout custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, product

I have a form in a single product page where user insert his informations (name, phone, country ,age ...) what I need to do is to display this information in billing details .

So, what I did is I added 2 fields to my form in single product , here is the code :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control alt" name="billing_vol" type="text"
                           placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( 'N° Vol : *', 'rentcar' ); ?>" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control alt" type="text" name="billing_cli_age"
                       placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( 'Age *', 'rentcar' ); ?>"
                     "
                >
            </div><div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php 
                        global $woocommerce;
                        $countries_obj   = new WC_Countries();
                        $countries   = $countries_obj->__get('countries');
                    ?>

                    <?php 
                        woocommerce_form_field('billing_country', array(
                        'type'       => 'select',
                        'class'      => array( 'chzn-drop' ),
                        'placeholder'    => __('Country'),
                        'options'    => $countries
                        )
                        );
                    ?>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Then I did the same thing In checkout page in  billing detail Form, I have added this 2 fields. Here is the code :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    $fields['billing']['billing_cli_age'] = array(
        'label'         => __('Age ', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('Age ', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'      => false,
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'         => true
    );

    $fields['billing']['billing_vol'] = array(
        'label'         => __('N° vol', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('N° vol', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'      => false,
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'         => true
    );
    return $fields;
}
```

Now I'm stuck , I don't know how to send the information added by user in form (that I have in single product) to billing details form in checkout Page.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete functional code to get product custom fields which submitted values when add-to-cart will filled our checkout custom fields.

The first function is just for my testing purpose. But your product custom-fields code should be inside the add-to-cart form, to get this working.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'action_before_add_to_cart_button',20 );
function action_before_add_to_cart_button() {
    ?>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div>
                <input class="form-control alt" name="billing_vol" type="text"
                       placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( 'N° Vol : *', 'rentcar' ); ?>">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control alt" type="text" name="billing_cli_age"
                       placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( 'Age *', 'rentcar' ); ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <?php
                // Getting the countries (simplified)
                $countries   = WC()->countries->get_countries();

                woocommerce_form_field('billing_country', array(
                    'type'       => 'select',
                    'class'      => array( 'chzn-drop' ),
                    'placeholder'    => __('Country'),
                    'options'    => $countries
                ) );
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
}
```

Here is the missing hooked function, that will pass into cart your product custom fields values:

```
// Store the data fields to cart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'action_save_my_custom_product_fields', 10, 2 );
function action_save_my_custom_product_fields( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {
    $bool = false;
    $data = array();
    if( isset( $_REQUEST['billing_vol'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['billing_vol'] = $_REQUEST['billing_vol'];
        $data['billing_vol'] = $_REQUEST['billing_vol'];
        $bool = true;
    }
    if( isset( $_REQUEST['billing_cli_age'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['billing_cli_age'] = $_REQUEST['billing_cli_age'];
        $data['billing_cli_age'] = $_REQUEST['billing_cli_age'];
        $bool = true;
    }
    if( isset( $_REQUEST['billing_country'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['billing_country'] = $_REQUEST['billing_country'];
        $data['billing_country'] = $_REQUEST['billing_country'];
        $bool = true;
    }
    if( $bool ) {
        // below statement make sure every add to cart action as unique line item
        $unique_key = md5( microtime().rand() );
        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['unique_key'] = $unique_key;
        $data['unique_key'] = $unique_key;
        WC()->session->set( 'custom_data', $data );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

As you can have multiple cart items, you will need to break the loop, to get only the first item custom values:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    // We break the loop to get the custom data from 1 cart item
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) break;

    $data = $cart_item['custom_data'];

    // COUNTRIES: Getting the countries (simplified)
    $countries   = WC()->countries->get_countries();
    $billing_country_key = $data['billing_country'];
    $billing_country_value = $countries[$billing_country_key];

    $fields['billing']['billing_cli_age'] = array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'label'         => __('Age ', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('Age ', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'      => false,
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'         => true,
        'default'       => $data['billing_cli_age'],
    );

    $fields['billing']['billing_vol'] = array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'label'         => __('N° vol', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('N° vol', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'      => false,
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'         => true,
        'default'       => $data['billing_vol'],
    );

    $fields['billing']['billing_country'] = array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'default' => $billing_country_key,
        'options' => array($billing_country_key => $billing_country_value),
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works.

> For country field is quiet complicated to get it work as Javascript/Ajax is also involved in it... With a unique "select" "option" it works, but with multiple select options it doesn't.

Comment: you are genius , yes it works , with this code I get all values that I have in single product except Country because I have a select field

Comment: @Hanane For a select field, it's very similar: If you update your question with all your fields, I can make it work, testing it… It's up to you

Comment: thanks Loic for your help. I edited my question in order to add the 3rd field " billing_country". so what I want is that the billing_country that I have in billing Details Form get the value from single product form .

Comment: Thanks again, it works perfectly . One thing I changed  this line **$billing_country_value = $countries[$country_key]; **  with this : **$billing_country_value = $countries[ $billing_country_key];**  just in case some one is looking for the same answer if you can update your answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Hanane Oh yes I have forget this one when I was renaming variables… I have updated this… thanks